# atool just hangs with `xargs -- zip -r test.csv` on Mac?

Tags: macos, archiving, xargs

First off, I couldn't seem to find why the `--` two dashes to `xargs`, but here's what I'm getting:

```
$ atool -E -a --format=zip words.csv
xargs -- zip -r words.csv
[...hangs...]
```

The docs are at https://linux.die.net/man/1/atool, and `-E` explains the command, so it looks like it's just trying to invoke the `zip` command. Why isn't it working though? I just installed with `brew install atool`:

```
==> Pouring atool--0.39.0.arm64_sonoma.bottle.2.tar.gz
```

How do I get this working? I would like to try all of the archive options for atool, not just zip, otherwise I would just use the zip command. atool looks great as a generic archiving tool, but it's not working for me yet. I tried reordering the options, and my `words.csv` is just a quick list of words in a csv.

It seems to work for unarchiving though:

```
$ atool -E -x swift-format.v0.46.tar.gz
mkdir Unpack-5037
tar xvzf swift-format.v0.46.tar.gz -C Unpack-5037
... lots of unarchiving files
```

But it didn't use xargs there, hmm....